# How to see a record that has a key that matches the previous records key in XML using LinQ to XML?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

How to see a record that has a key that matches the previous records key in XML using LinQ to XML using C#?. Please refer the below example, The record key is `customerId`.

```
<Node>
  <Customer>
    <customerId>1</CustomerId>
  </Customer>
  <Address>
    <customerId>1</CustomerId>
    <Address1>ABVC</Address1>
  </Address>
  <Address>
    <customerId>2</CustomerId>
    <Address1>ABVC</Address1>
  </Address>
</Node>
```

Comment: What is your definition of "previous"?

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml = XElement.Load("test.xml");

var id = xml.Element("Customer").Element("customerId").Value;

var address = xml.Elements("Address")
    .First(a => a.Element("customerId").Value == id)
    .Element("Address1").Value;
```

Note: opening and closing tags in your xml do not match. Fix it.